# Visual studio code wraps html too much

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I have updated visual studio code to latest version.

It just changed formatting in html files. All my html file changes when i format again.

It wraps like we are coding in tablet mode leaving empty space like below 
[image]

Can anyone help me with this. It creates issue when more then one developer is working on same project. Just slight different version of visual studio code changes format.

Comment: Do you want it not to wrap lines at all? Or just wrap them at a different point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to turn the wrap line length you can go to `Preferences` -> `Settings` and search for `wrap`. There you will find `HTML › Format: Wrap Line Length` and you can change that value.