# Rewrap HTML code in Visual Studio Code to a column

Tags: visual-studio-code

I haven't figured out how to rewrap HTML code in Visual Studio Code. For example, if I have this:

```
<html>
   <p>
       This long paragraph should wrap at some column I can define
       but I couldn't find a way to get it
       to wrap. Searched for an extension but couldn't find one.
   </p>
</html>
```

I really want this:

```
<html>
   <p>
       This long paragraph should wrap at some column I can define but I couldn't find a way to 
       get it to wrap. Searched for an extension but couldn't find one.
   </p>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55178422/visual-studio-code-wraps-html-too-much/55178513#55178513

Comment: No, that doesn't re-wrap. That only limits the line length. Reformatting the code doesn't change anything inside a <p> tag.